# how to implement user level access control on istore catalog?

Tags: oracle, erp

I am trying to implement a functionality in Oracle istore 11i by which

if there are 3 catalog's say Catalog A,Catalog B,Catalog C.
And there are 3 users say X,Y,Z
then 
X should view the catalog A.
Y should view only catalog B
Z should view only catalog C.
Is there a way to implement this functionality??
Also X,Y, and Z should be able to search only through their respective catalogs.

X should search only A
Y should search only B
Z should search only C.

Kindly let me know how this can be implemented using Oracle istore 11i?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Oracle istore, but at the database level, you could use fine-grained access control (part of Virtual Private Database).